# Extracting text from PDF with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, text, ghostscript

I am using Ghostscript 9.20 to extract the text from a PDF document that contains only two lines of text:

```
Hello world…
A beautiful day!
```

The code applied is:

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o output.txt input.pdf
```

However, the the output is:

```
  䠀攀氀氀漀 眀漀爀氀搀☠ 
  䄀 戀攀愀甀琀椀昀甀氀 搀愀礀℀
```

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: The encoding of fonts in a pdf does not necessarily have anything to do with normal ASCII or UTF encodings.

Comment: Please check a hexadecimal view of your "Chinese" text. It reads "Hello world… ਀  A beautiful day! " (where `਀` is `0x0A00`, which probably got messed up because of copying your output from the screen).

Comment: So, how do I fix my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the 9.20 release which affected *certain* kinds of text extraction. Not all, it depends on the input, and since you haven't supplied that its impossible to tell if your particular input file is affected.

To fix it you can:

1. Clone Ghostscript from our Git repository, build and test the latest code.
2. Wait until the next release (March) and test that.
3. Open a bug report and someone will look at it. Though that won't actually help you. If its already been fixed, you'll then have to choose either 1 or 2. If it hasn't been fixed then you'll need to wait until it is and then follow either 1 or 2, but at least you'll have helped improve the product.

Comment: Is that bug related to big-endian/little-endian Unicode 16-bit text?

Comment: That is indeed the result of the problem. Because Adobe (some time back) changed the definition of the ToUnicode CMap we had to recode a load of stuff which had some unexpected side effects. The ToUnicode generation (and text extraction code) use heuristics a lot, because we are often working in the absence of concrete data. In this case a particular fallback had an invalid assumption after the rewrite, which meant that UTF16-BE was actually being handled with the wrong endian-ness internally.

Comment: Yep, right on. I just tried with version 9.18 and it worked fine.